# How to append to a list within a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

Probably an easy one but I'm can't quite tweak this. I'm trying to seperate the numbers from a list (duplicates and unique) and put them into a dictionary with two keys representing both.

Is there a way to store/append the numbers from the list into their perspective keys. With my code its only the last number in the list that is stored into the key i'd like. sorry if that's not very clear!

```
numbers = [20, 20, 20, 2, 10, 10, 1]

dictionary = {}


for items in numbers:
    i = numbers.count(items)
    if i == 1:
        dictionary["unique"] = items
    else: 
        dictionary["duplicate"] = items

print(dictionary)
```

I was expecting something like:

{'unique': 2, 1, 'duplicate': 20, 20, 10}

Answer (score 1):

Make a dictionary of lists:

```
dictionary = {
    "unique": [],
    "duplicate": []
}

for items in numbers:
    i = numbers.count(items)
    if i == 1:
        dictionary["unique"].append(items)
    else: 
        dictionary["duplicate"].append(items)
```

You can also simplify with a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(numbers)
dictionary = {
    "unique": [n for n in numbers if c[n] == 1],
    "duplicate": [n for n in numbers if c[n] > 1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library `collections` has a `Counter` class which can count occurences:

```py
import collections

numbers = [20, 20, 20, 2, 10, 10, 1]
counter = collections.Counter(numbers)
counter
# output: Counter({20: 3, 2: 1, 10: 2, 1: 1})
```

From here, you can see that 20 appears 3 times, 2 appears 1 time, ... I recommend to use this `counter` data structure directly and treat it like a regular dictionary, such as:

```py
>>> counter[20]
3

>>> counter[2]
1

>>> for number, count in counter.items(): print(f"{number}: {count}")
20: 3
2: 1
10: 2
1: 1
```

If you still insist on creating a dictionary with unique and duplicate, then here it is:

```py
dictionary = {"unique": [], "duplicate": []}
for number in numbers:
    count = counter[number]
    if count == 1:
        dictionary["unique"].append(number)
    else:
        dictionary["duplicate"].append(number)
```